# JPQL join translation policy

Tags: mysql, jpa, jakarta-ee, jpql

I am having trouble searching in my application database due to the translated query resulting from my JPQL query.

Consider the following Structure:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="pc")
public class PC {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="DEFAULTOS")
    private Software defaultOS;
    ...}

@Entity
@Table(name="software")
public class Software {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;
    ...}
```

Here is the search query I'm doing:

```
public List<PC> getPcsInstalled(Software soft){
    TypedQuery<PC> lQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT lPC FROM PC lPC"
            + " WHERE lPC.defaultOS IS NULL"
            + " OR lPC.defaultOS.name NOT LIKE :param", PC.class);
    lQuery.setParameter("param", soft.getName());
    return lQuery.getResultList();  
}
```

Which translates to:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.NAME, t1.DEFAULTOS FROM software t0, pc t1
WHERE (((t1.DEFAULTOS IS NULL) OR NOT (t0.NAME LIKE "Linux"))
AND (t0.ID = t1.DEFAULTOS))
```

The tables are "joined" with the latest condition `(t0.ID = t1.DEFAULTOS)`. Which automatically filters any PC having DEFAULTOS = NULL (which is not what I want obviously).

The query I expected was:

```
 SELECT t1.ID, t1.NAME, t1.DEFAULTOS FROM pc t1
 LEFT JOIN software t0 ON t1.DEFAULTOS = t0.ID
 WHERE (((t1.DEFAULTOS IS NULL) OR NOT (t0.NAME LIKE "Linux")))
```

Of course I can rewrite the JPQL query to specify the LEFT JOIN explicitely, but I was wondering : **Is there a way to have the LEFT JOIN as the default policy to join tables?**

In fact this is just a simple example, in my project I build much more complex queries and adding the needed LEFT JOIN would be very complex in the actual code.

For information, I'm using Glassfish 4.0 with EclipseLink and a MySQL database.

Comment: No. The JPA spec defines the join type to use when doing implicit joins ... INNER.

Comment: Too bad, thanks for you answer anyway